# Using my login script, is there an easy way to create an admin session?

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, admin

Hello please see below for my login script which I want to admin "isAdmin" too.

```
 <?php

    session_start();

    $username = "#####";
    $password = "#####";
    $hostname = "#####";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("logindashboard", $dbhandle);

    $user = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['user'] );
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['pass'] );

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logindashboard.login WHERE user='".$user."' and pass='".$pass."'");
    if( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header('Location: index2.php');
        }else{
        echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
        }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

In the database I have a field of each user called "admin" this is either 1 or 0.

Is there a way to create a specific session called "isAdmin" which on my homepage if it's detected I can display a div?

I tried using the another select in the IF statement, but it failed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Despite of the answers you got. You should NOT use mysql_* it is *deprecated* also it is completely open to sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
  $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = ($row['admin'])? true : false;
  header('Location: index2.php');
}else{
  echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
}
```

**mysql_ is now deprecated, you should use [`mysqli_`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logindashboard.login WHERE user='".$user."' and pass='".$pass."'");
if( mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $_SESSION['adminCheck']=$row['admin'];
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header('Location: index2.php');
}else{
    echo 'Incorrect Username or Password';
}
```

and in displaying page

```
if($_SESSION['adminCheck']=='1'){
    //display div
}
```

Comment: Hello, I followed this. It allows me to log in, as a test I just wanted to echo  "echo "Logged in as [Admin]";"

When logged in as admin this doesn't appear, I have:

<?php require_once('../../../.config2.php'); 
session_start();
if( ! $_SESSION['loggedIn'] ) {
    // not logged in redirect direct to login page
    header('Location: index.php');
}
if($_SESSION['adminCheck']=='1'){
    //display div
 echo "Logged in as [Admin]";
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Let we assume you have row to store admin value as **isadmin** **1 or 0**